# Replace original jpg after Image Magick Convert -profile

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, color-profile

I have created a .bat using Image Magick's 'convert' command to convert color profiles for .jpgs. The conversion works correctly however, the converted .jpg files are moved from source path to path of the .bat script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set IMCONV="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Data\conversion_script\convert.exe"
Path C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Data\conversion_script\ 

FOR %%f IN (C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Upload\*.jpg) DO (
%IMCONV% %%f -profile "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Data\color_profile\sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm" %%~nf.jpg
)
```

I am unable to find a solution other than adding a second command to move the converted .jpgs back to source folder & replace the non-converted .jpgs. I wish to avoid this second command.

```
move /y "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\*.jpg" "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Upload" >nul
```

Any thoughts on how to execute the script to replace the old .jpgs with the newly converted .jps in the source folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make backup first and then try the following two suggestions.

#### Use `mogrify` instead of a loop

```
mogrify -profile xyz.icm "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.5\_Upload\*.jpg"
```

#### Use a loop, but change the output filename

```
FOR %% IN ... DO (
   convert %%f -profile xyz.icm %%f
)
```

Comment: Excellent advice. Thanks @Mark Setchell!